# Ember.js - one view multiple layouts (logged in/not logged in)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my current Ember project I have an authentication system in place. Certain pages are view-able only by authenticated users. Checking if the user is authenticated and controlling access to a page is simple enough, so no problems there.

The issue is I have certain pages that are view-able by both authenticated and non-authenticated users. An authenticated user sees a different navigation (top and side bars) than a non-authenticated user (more navigation options, settings, etc.). I want to change which layout is used based on whether the user is authenticated or not. The problem is it seems I can only set one layout to a view.

The general code is something like the following:

Layouts:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="authenticated_layout">
  //authenticated layout mark up
  {{yield}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="not_authenticated_layout">
  //not_authenticated layout mark up
  {{yield}}
</script>
```

Article Template (articles can be viewed by authenticated or non-authenticated users):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="article">
  //article mark up
</script>
```

Article View:

```
App.ArticleView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "article",
  layoutName: //want this to be based on authentication state
  //other view code
})
```

I've of having a different view for each layout and rendering the template with the view based on whether the user is authenticated or not. The issue I see there is the `ArticlesView` does more than just set the layout, and I really would rather not have two separate views that only differ by their `layoutName` property.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a computed property in your layoutName could work.

Pseudo code:

```
App.ArticleView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "article",
  layoutName: function() {
    // you can use your own logic to know if the user is authenticated
    // but don't forget to add in the property(dependenKey), if needed
    return App.get('currentUser') ? 'authenticated_layout' : 'not_authenticated_layout';
  }.property('App.currentUser')
})
```

Comment: Ah yes, that works. I didn't realize a computed property could be used there, but it makes sense. Thanks.