# Ember.js Layout

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am just getting warm with ember.js and would like to create a single page application with it.
Due to the nature of the application, I will have multiple "major" layouts at some point.

After the user logged into the application, I need to display the user name based on an ajax call. I did not yet understand how I best implement this in ember.js, because this (at least to me) is outside of any view hierarchy.

I played around with using the "into" option of the render method.

```
App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('layout');

    this.render('test',{
       into: 'layout'
    });
  },
});
```

I thought this would also call the layout route and load its model. Unfortunately it did not do that.

I went over to define a layout with a {{yield}} directive

```
<div>
  <div class="container" id="header">
    {{loginUser.userName}}
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="main-content">
    {{yield}}
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="footer">
    Just some static footer
   </div>
</div>
```

and my view like

```
App.TestView = Ember.View.extend({
  layoutName: 'layout'
});
```

The rendering works fine, but I fail to see where I can best inject the user data.
Ideally this should be transparent for all views that make use of this layout. So my thought was to work with inheritance, but did not come to a working solution yet.

Am I completely off track here or does this somehow make sense?

**UPDATE**

I put the example in here: http://jsfiddle.net/Efz8N/4/

Comment: Actually, it seems that this might be a good solution to this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983390/ember-js-one-view-multiple-layouts-logged-in-not-logged-in   I will play with this and see if it can get me where I want to be.

Comment: Seems not to be working, because again the LayoutView is not called, but only the TestView.

Comment: Hey atlan, will you show the test route/controllers (if they exist)

Comment: I do not have any controllers setup for this. I just added a short example in jsFiddle making use of the index route.

Answer (score 0):

Layout's are backed by the controller which is backing the view using the layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/WHvCZ/

```
loginUserFullName:function(){
    return this.get('controllers.application.loginUser') || 'not in';
}.property('controllers.application.loginUser')
```

Comment: Thx, but, in the example I would still need to implement the computed property in all controllers that make use of the layout. Is there a way to have that logic on the layout piece? In all setups that I tried so far, no layout controller or view implementation has been called. In the meantime I have a solution that I will post later this evening. I created a mixin that I add to all controllers that make use of the layout. I do not like it that much, but it works.

Comment: Yeah, layouts are just that, layouts, the logic all gets passed to the item using the layout.  The mixin is a perfect way to handle it, then you don't duplicate logic

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it now. I created a mixin that I can use in any Controller that makes use of the layout. This way I at least do not have to implement this multiple times:

```
App.LayoutHandler = Ember.Mixin.create({
  loginUserFullName: function() {
    var name = App.get("loginUser")?App.get("loginUser"):"";

    return name;
  }.property("App.loginUser"),
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend(App.LayoutHandler, {

});
```

Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Efz8N/6/